# Compatible for matrices

Tags: functional-analysis

We know that an $r \times n$ matrix $A=(\alpha_{jk})$ defines a linear operator from the vector space $X$ of all ordered $n$-tuples of numbers into the vector space $Y$ of all ordered $r$-tuples of numbers.

Suppose that any norm $\|\cdot\|_1$ is given on $X$ and any norm $\|\cdot\|_2$ is given on $Y$. A norm $\|\cdot\|$ on $Z$ (all complex $r$ by $n$ matrices) is said to be compatible with $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$ if $\|Ax\|_2 \leq \|A\|\cdot \|x\|_1$.

**Show that the norm defined by 
$\|A\|= \sup\frac{\|Ax\|_2}{ \|x\|_1}$  where $x\in X$ is compatible with $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$.**

Please help me, if you have any good idea about my question. I tried to firstly prove that the two norms are equivalent. But I do not.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks. I tried to edit it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I made some improvements to your edits, for future reference feel free to take a look at what I did by clicking on "edited X ago" above my name. You should probably also clarify what the space $Z$ is here.

Comment: Thank you. Also, the space Z is all complex r by n matrices.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\n}[1]{\left\Vert #1 \right\Vert}
\newcommand{\0}{\vec 0}$
This result is fairly trivial. Let $x_0 \in X$ be arbitrary. Then
$$
\n{A} := \sup_{\substack{x \in X \\ x \ne \0}} \frac{\n{Ax}_2}{\n{x}_1} \ge \frac{\n{Ax_0}_2}{\n{x_0}_1} \implies \n{A} \n{x_0}_1\ge \n{Ax_0}_2
$$
The first inequality follows from the definition of supremum.

That $x_0$ is arbitrary gives compatibility.